# Connecting domain route53 to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I had bought some time ago domain in route53.
Today I wanted to use s3 instead of old solution.
My example.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com works fine.
In hosted zone I have added as a alias this site.
Then I copied DNS servers from hosted zone, and replaced them in domain.

Domain configuration:
[image]
Hosted zone:
[image]

What I did wrong that its not working ? :( Thanks

Comment: How much time has passed since you changed your DNS settings? Depending on the DNS configuration (old settings), it may take up to 48 hours for the changes to take effect.

Comment: For sure not 48 hours.. Uhm I thought as everything is on amazon it will go faster :)

Comment: Also as a quick tip, you might want to consider putting [CloudFront in front of your s3 bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html), that way you it caches files at their edge server (multi-region) and you can get a [free SSL cert applied for your domain](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-certificate-manager-deploy-ssltls-based-apps-on-aws/) as well (custom domain https access). The caveat being you have to host your bucket and generate your SSL cert in us-east-1 (where the CloudFront deploy infra lives).

Comment: @ChrisWhite wait: *"The caveat being you have to host your bucket and generate your SSL cert in us-east-1"*  Cert, yes, but not the bucket.  The bucket can be in **any** region and still work with an ACM cert from us-east-1 on CloudFront.

Comment: If you'd like to know, now, what's going on sooner rather than later, @Baku, mention the domain name and we should easily be able to pinpoint the problem.  The 48 hour thing is a theoretical worst case.  It's normally much shorter, though how long it takes depends primarily on how you had it set *before* you changed it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I meant to put in "unless you want to pay region transfer fees" for that but forgot. For a few static files not too bad, but if you plan to serve up media files that might get a bit on the costly side.

Comment: @ChrisWhite that's actually still not the case.  Check the S3 pricing pages for any region.  *"Data Transfer OUT From Amazon S3 To Amazon CloudFront $0.000 per GB."*  The CloudFront connection to us-east-1 is only the control plane.  If, say, I have a bucket in London and I access it from a browser in Prague via a CloudFront distribution and there's a cache miss, the edge in Prague connects more or less directly to the bucket in London -- the actual traffic doesn't flow through us-east-1.